# How to find records where a single value among the multiple records is null?

Tags: sql

I have a table `table_A`

```
rec_id    email
1            null
1            a@gmail.com
2            null
2            null
3            x@gmail.com
3            null
3            null
4            y@gmail.com
4            z@gmail.com
```

I want the records where at least one of the rec_id has values, but others has null. But I don't want the records that has null values for all rec_id and also don't want the records which has values for all rec_id

the expected output:

```
rec_id  email
1            null
1            a@gmail.com
3            x@gmail.com
3            null
3            null
```

I think this answers the question;

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A E1
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A E2 WHERE E2.EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND E1.REC_ID = E2.REC_ID)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A E3 WHERE E1.EMAIL IS NULL AND E1.REC_ID = E3.REC_ID)
```

Comment: MySQL or Snowflake? If MySQL - what is its precise version?

Comment: What about `rec_id` which have more than one non-NULL value? both the same and different..

Comment: consider cases where rec_id is not null and only multiple rec_id exists

Comment: We may consider anything. But if your structure cannot provide/guarantee this then you must envision and process such case.

Answer (score 1):

Use a GROUP BY on `rec_id` to compute a pair of counts:

- COUNT(*) of *all* rows with the given ID, and
- SUM of the non-NULL rows, or equivalently of the NULL rows, using a [CASE WHEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) expression

Armed with those two derived columns,
you will be in a good position to pick out
rows that qualify according to your use case.

You may find it convenient to structure the query with a
[CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)
clause.

---

When you work out a solution for your environment,
[report back](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)
with the technical details you settled on.

Comment: The question is tagged for MySQL and Snowflake. You provide links to PostgreSQL documentation.. why?

Comment: Please check with the answer

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A E1
WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A E2 WHERE E2.EMAIL IS NOT NULL AND E1.REC_ID = E2.REC_ID)
AND EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A E3 WHERE E1.EMAIL IS NULL AND E1.REC_ID = E3.REC_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It will reduce the performance issue as well

```sql
Select
    A.*
From
    table_A A JOIN 
(
    Select rec_id From table_A WHERE email is NULL 
    INTERSECT
    Select rec_id From table_A WHERE email is NOT NULL
) B ON (A.rec_id = B.rec_id)
```

Output will diplay as expected
[image]